# Morphism in commutative square strict?

Tags: gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, topological-groups, norms, topological-vector-spaces

Let $G,H$ be topological groups and $f:G\rightarrow H$ a continuous group homomorphism.

Then $f$ is said to be strict if $G/\mathrm{Ker}(f) \cong \mathrm{Im}(f)$ is an isomorphism of topological groups.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$ for some prime $p$ and

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
V @>\pi_1>> W\\
@V f V V= @VV g V\\
V' @>>\pi_2> W'
\end{CD}

a commutative diagram of (
non-archimedean) normed $K$-vector spaces (not necessarily complete) such that
$f$ is strict and $\pi_i$ are quotient maps, hence strict too. Then I wonder if $g$ is strict too?

Comment: The maps are morphisms of vector spaces, not just of groups? \\ What does "normed $K$-vector space" mean if $K$ is not $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ (e.g., if it has positive characteristic)?

Comment: I adjusted it. Hope that helps. Yeah morphism of vector spaces.

Comment: A normed $\mathbb Q_p$-vector space $V$ has a map $V \to \mathbb Q_p$, or a map $V \to \mathbb R$?  If the former, is there a 'positivity' condition? \\ You are not assuming your spaces are finite-dimensional, correct?

Comment: @LSpice It is all standard terminology. Norms take values in _linearly ordered_ abelian groups. Usually you take $\Bbb R$ as the target, since all small orders embed into it. Of course, every finite dimensional morphism is strict.

Comment: @DenisT, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428705/morphism-in-commutative-square-strict#comment1102776_428705), the reason I ask is that of course $\mathbb R$-valued norms are more common, but there is also a (very different!) theory of $\mathbb Q_p$-vector spaces with $\mathbb Q_p$-valued 'norms'.  Anyway it is surely easy for the questioner to say what they meant.